# Reverse $.each output in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, reverse

I'm making a little secret tool. The output will be in a table, and on the left-hand side I'd like to list the numbers I have stored in `$.each()`. So here's my code:

```
$.each([1,2,3,4,5], function(i, l){


   var lol = (some math stuff here);

   $("#output").append("<tr><td>" + l + "</td><td>" + lol + "</td><tr>");

});
```

What this does is output  the following:

```
1.  lol1
2.  lol2
3.  lol3
4.  lol4
5.  lol5
```

What I'm trying to do is reverse that `l` value but leave everything else alone so that the output instead looks like this:

```
5. lol1
4. lol2
3. lol3
2. lol4
1. lol5
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a copy of the array and then reverse that one. Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/naRKF/

And the code (the HTML isn't the same as yours, but the JS technique is what you should focus on/use):

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var arr2 = arr1.slice().reverse(); //creates a copy and reverses it

var html = '';
for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
    html += '<div>' + arr2[i] + '.' + ' lol' + arr1[i] + '</div>';
}

$('body').append(html);
```

Comment: DUDE. 
This works perfectly. I really appreciate it. I tried doing the whole `for(i = 0...)` stuff before and couldn't get it to work. Thanks so much!

Comment: For what it's worth, a standard for loop is probably quicker than jQuery's $.each() loop. $.each() really exists so that you can easily iterate over the properties of an object, as opposed to the items in an array. And one other thing: be aware that arr2 = arr1 does NOT create a copy of the array. It simply creates two separate variables that reference the same array. So if you were to do arr2 = arr1; arr2.reverse() -- you'd actually be reversing arr1 as well because they are the same. arr1.slice() is the trick that actually creates the copy.

Answer (score 2):

`$.each()` will always iterate the array in the correct order. You want to use a `for` loop for this one, rather then jQuery's `$.each()`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using `for` before and I couldn't get it just right. maxedison's answer solved this problem. Thanks for the contribution!

Answer (score 2):

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
$.each(x.reverse(), function(i, l){
    var lol = (some math stuff here)
    $("#output").append("<tr><td>" + l + "</td><td>" + lol + "</td><tr>")
})
```

Comment: This reverses the output, but does not invert the numbering like he wants. lol2 is with 2, but should be with 4. http://jsfiddle.net/EEuN8/

Comment: Hmm. This didn't work, but storing the array as a separate variable is a good move and ended up working for me with maxedison's answer. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.each([1,2,3,4,5].reverse(),function(i,l){...
```

Basically since you are using a native array, you can simply reverse it to go in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
var counter = arr.length
$.each(arr, function(i, l){

   var lol = "lol"+l;

   $("#output").append("<tr><td>" + counter-- + ".&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>" + lol + "</td><tr>");

});
```

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bxa25/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
var a=[1,2,3,4,5]
$.each(a, function(i, l){
   var lol = (some math stuff here);
   $("#output").append("<tr><td>" + a[a.length-i] + "</td><td>" + lol + "</td><tr>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Soemthing like this should help:

```
function test(arr) {
    if ($.isArray(arr)) {
        var reverse = arr.slice().reverse();
        $(arr).each(function(i) {
            console.log(reverse[i] + ". lol" + this);
        });
    }
}

test([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```